# ArcGIS Silverlight API 2.4 support for Microsoft Silverlight 5.0?

Tags: arcgis-silverlight-api, silverlight

Please let me know whether ArcGIS Silverlight API 2.4 version officially supports or CERTIFIES Microsoft Silverlight 5.0.?

Comment: Silverlight 'should be backwards compatible - though have had issues with other geo software that cause the Catastrophic failure.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know about ArcGIS API for Silverlight 2.4, but on the assumption that you may by now be using a later release, I note that the [ArcGIS API for Silverlight 3.1](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/silverlight-api/concepts/index.html#//016600000005000000) installation certainly seems to support Silverlight 5.